# reCaptcha does not reload when using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, security, recaptcha

I'm building a ASP.NET MCV application, and I have this page where the user can do a search. I'm using Ajax to get the result. Here's the structure of my page (simplified) :

```
// The part of my page that does not change
<div id = "searchForm">
    <input id="txWhat" type="text"/>
    <input id="txWhere" type="text"/>

    <input id="idBnSearch" type="submit" value="Search"/>
</div>

// The result container
<div "resultContainer">
    // Here is where I put the result, and the captcha
</div>
```

What I want to do, is to add a reCaptcha every 20 operations of search. So, I added a partial view witch contains the captcha, and the idea is, whene the search operations number get to 20, I display the Captcha partial view, and if the reCaptcha was typed correctly, then, get the result of the typed a criteria.

The problem is, because I'm using Ajax, the captcha does not load (no text to type). Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: recall captcha on $ajax: beforeSend function()?

Comment: how to call it via Ajax ? I'm using the HTML Helper : Html.GenerateCaptcha()

Comment: any sort of classes or plugin for the catpcha?

Comment: Yes, it's alled reCaptcha

Comment: you can read the documentation on https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display; and for the demo: http://www.google.com/recaptcha/demo/ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i assume you are familiar with jquery AJAX.

```
$.ajax(function(){
  beforeSend: function(){
     Recaptcha.create("YOUR_KEY", 'captchadiv', {
            tabindex: 1,
            theme: "clean",
            callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
     });
 }
})
```

for the demo http://www.google.com/recaptcha/demo/ajax